# WSO2 APIM 2.0 deployment

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to understand WSO2 APIM components and deployment scenarios but the terminology is confusing/vague for me. Clustering vs distributed deployments, profiles, and Port Offsets.

Basically I'd like to deploy a minimal 5 node setup where:

**Node #** **(Location) Purpose**

1. (DMZ) the GW (worker=True right?) and KeyManager
2. (DMZ) 2nd GW node (as above) for GW & KeyManager
3. (non-dmz) the Management Console, MySQL master
4. (non-dmz) the Publisher UI,TrafficManager, MySQL slave
5. (DMZ)     the Store

[image: looks like this]

**Questions:**

1. Should I use -DportOffset=0 on all nodes?
2. What -Dprofile=?? do I need to use on each of the 5 nodes?
3. The 2 gateway nodes will be load-balanced by an F5 load balancer
   for incoming api-traffic. What port is used there, 9443 or 9763?
4. What ports need to be accessible on the DMZ hosts for this to work?
   I assume 3306,9443,9763,8280,8243,7711, and 9999,11111 if JMX reqd

Please don't point me to the documentation, that's what is confusing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running the key manager nodes, Store node in the DMZ is not recommended as they need db access. If you are using multi tenancy, you cannot host gateway worker nodes in the DMZ as well due to db access. What you can do is host those nodes in LAN and have a reverse proxy in the DMZ to expose the endpoints on the Gateway and Store. If you do not use multi tenancy, then you can run gateway worker nodes in the DMZ as dbs are not used.

1. As you are running multiple WSO2 servers in a single server you need to use port offsets to avoid conflicts. Default port offset is 0. You can run one WSO2 server with default port offset. For the other server you need to use port offset 1 or any value other than 0. You can start the server by giving the -DportOffset=1 at the startup. Best way is to change the value offset to 1 in /repository/conf/carbon.xml so that you do not need to provide the -DportOffset value at the startup.
2. -Dprofile is denote the profile which API Manager should start. If you start with -Dprofile=api-publisher, it would only starts the front end/backend features relevant to the API Publisher. Running product profiles are mostly recommended as it would only load relevant features of the profile. You can use profiles in your deployment as you are running 6 profiles of API Manager.
3. I think you are referring gateway worker nodes which serve API traffic. If so, it will use passthrough ports that are 8280(http) and 8243(https). Requests can serve using both. 9443 and 9763 are servlet ports are those will not used in gateway worker nodes and only in gateway manager node for service calls.

   4. My recommendation is you should revise this setup as you are running nodes in DMZ which have db access.

Comment: I was planning to open port 3306 on the firewall between the LAN & DMZ so that my DMZ hosts can access MySQL.

Comment: Why is a DB not required if I'm not using multi-tenancy?

Comment: @
What's still not clear is the -profile and portOffset properties.
If I want to run a KeyMgr and a GatewayWorker on a single host, 
do I need to run 1 JVM ike this: 
  DIR/bin/wso_server.sh -DportOffset=0 -Dprofile=gateway-worker -Dprofile=gateway-worker -DworkerNode=true -Dprofile=api-key-manager             
or do I need 2 JVMs like: 
 DIR1/bin/wso_server.sh -DportOffset=0 -Dprofile=gateway-worker -Dprofile=gateway-worker -DworkerNode=true

 DIR2/bin/wso_server.sh  -DportOffset=1 -Dprofile=api-key-manager

Comment: DB access is not required only for gateway nodes when multi tenancy is not used. When multi tenancy is not used, gateway nodes does not need to access shared dbs. In tenancy mode, tenant specific data is stored in dbs and hence required db access.

Comment: Based on your TPS requirement you need to decide how many jvms you should run in the system. Do a performance test to decide. You cannot combine multiple profiles and run in a single jvm. But you can run single jvm and start the node in default profile. All the configurations should be changed to act that jvm to perform as key manager as well as the gateway node.

Comment: Let's assume you go with 1 jvm which act as key manager as well as the gateway. Then you can start as ./wso2server.sh start.  If you run 2 jvms and key manager can start as ./wso2server.sh -Dprofile=api-key-manager start. For gatway worker node it can start as ./wso2server.sh -DportOffset=1 -Dprofile=gateway-worker -DworkerNode=true start.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I use -DportOffset=0 on all nodes?

It depends on how do you set up those nodes. If all of these servers in the same node (machine), you must use different port offset as all the API Manager servers use those port, so, there will be port conflicts.

> What -Dprofile=?? do I need to use on each of the 5 nodes?
>   It will adjust the ports used by API Manager so that, there won't be any port conflicts between them if you are running on same node.
>
> The 2 gateway nodes will be load-balanced by an F5 load balancer for
>   incoming api-traffic. What port is used there, 9443 or 9763?

For API requests/responses handling, you need 9763.

> What ports need to be accessible on the DMZ hosts for this to work? I
>   assume 3306,9443,9763,8280,8243,7711, and 9999,11111 if JMX reqd
>   Yes, it's correct.

Further, you can use [WSO2 support](http://wso2.com/support/) any issues you encountered.